# Magento limit number of subcategories of a category

Tags: category, ce-1.9.0.1

```
$load_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());

$categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren();
```

I want only 3 subcategories, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$load_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $load_category->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//in case you want only the active categories
;
$children->setPage(1,3); //limit to only 3 items - it means set page number 1, and limit 3.
foreach ($children as $child) {
    //do something with $child var
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marius this is working fine, but can we do it via function, i mean here we are performing a query in Magento style and i was using a function.

Comment: @We'wake. Just create your own helper that receives as paramters the category id or object and the limit. You will be able then to call it like this: $children = `Mage::helper('your_helper')->getChildCategories($category, $limit);`